# NServiceBus SatelliteLauncher exception

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I've got the following EndpointConfig.cs

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, IWantCustomInitialization, AsA_Server
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure
            .With(GetAllAssemblies())
            .XmlSerializer()
            .UseTransport<SqlServer>()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .UseNHibernateSubscriptionPersister()
            .UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister()
            .UseNHibernateSagaPersister()
            .UseNHibernateGatewayPersister()
            .UnicastBus()
            .PurgeOnStartup(false);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

```
2013-10-09 16:15:40,780 [16] ERROR NServiceBus.Satellites.SatelliteLauncher [(null)] <(null)> - Satellite NServiceBus.Gateway.Receiving.GatewayReceiver, NServiceBus.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
System.Exception: Failed to start listener for http://localhost/NserviceBus/ make sure that you have admin privileges ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
    at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
    at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
    at NServiceBus.Gateway.Channels.Http.HttpChannelReceiver.Start(String address, Int32 numWorkerThreads) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Gateway\Channels\Http\HttpChannelReceiver.cs:line 36
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at NServiceBus.Gateway.Channels.Http.HttpChannelReceiver.Start(String address, Int32 numWorkerThreads) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Gateway\Channels\Http\HttpChannelReceiver.cs:line 40
    at NServiceBus.Gateway.Receiving.IdempotentChannelReceiver.Start(Channel channel, Int32 numWorkerThreads) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Gateway\Receiving\IdempotentChannelReceiver.cs:line 34
    at NServiceBus.Gateway.Receiving.GatewayReceiver.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Gateway\Receiving\GatewayReceiver.cs:line 71
    at NServiceBus.Satellites.SatelliteLauncher.StartSatellite(SatelliteContext ctx) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Satellites\SatelliteLauncher.cs:line 107
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running in Visual Studio or this problem's in production? The simplest fix is to run VS as admin. Otherwise google NETSH HTTP ADD URLACL

Comment: It's happening when I ran it from VS, but I'm running it with admin rights. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to enable the gateway component?
If not, remove the `.UseNHibernateGatewayPersister()`

The underlying issue has nothing to do with NServiceBus specifically. The account you're running Visual Studio under doesn't have the rights to reserve a HTTP/S port. The same thing happens when self hosting WCF endpoints.

More information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)

Comment: I just copied it from an example, I'm still making it onto version 4, last I used was 2.6.=, so there a lot to figure out. But since you touch the thing what is this gateway component all about?

Comment: I just removed this and the exception is not showing, but I'm keen to know what this Gateway stuff is all about?

Comment: http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859548-the-gateway-and-multi-site-distribution